# How i can use five different SQl Queries in the same gridview from the same table

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I use five different SQl Queries in the same gridview from the same table with different parameters

```
select count(distinct callingnumber) as UniqueCaller,count(callingnumber) as      numberOfCall from FCR1  where callnumberpercallreason >15;

select count(distinct callingnumber) as UniqueCaller,count(callingnumber) as numberOfCall from FCR1  where callnumberpercallreason between 2 and 6 and callreasonname='Mobile/GSM>VAS-CRBT>CRBT Service Deactivation';
```

=========output============

```
Calling frequency   Unique Caller   No of Call
15                  7               116
B/n 14-11           11              133
B/n 10-8            50              412
B/n 7-2             8528            20635
One Times           46219           46219
Total               54815           67515
```

Comment: If selected columns are same then you can use `union`.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are the same you can use union between the two queries like this:

```
select count(distinct callingnumber) as UniqueCaller,count(callingnumber) as      numberOfCall from FCR1  where callnumberpercallreason >15;
union
select count(distinct callingnumber) as UniqueCaller,count(callingnumber) as numberOfCall from FCR1  where callnumberpercallreason between 2 and 6 and callreasonname='Mobile/GSM>VAS-CRBT>CRBT Service Deactivation';
```

if your columns are different you can create blanks for the columns that are different for example:

```
 select col1, col2, col3 from table1
 union
 select col1, '', col4 from table2
```